# How can you add proactive messages dialog to dialog stack, created by RunAsync method?

Tags: c#, dialog, botframework

I am trying to connect my Root Dialog with proactive messages dialog, invoked from controller. 
I want to create a logic in OnMessageActivityAsync method to allow me to invoke RunAsync method on dialog for handling proactive messages dialog and logic which is currently present in RootDialog.

Do you know if it is possible?
Should I register those dialogs separately?

Thank you,
Jan

Comment: Please include what you've tried. These kinds of things can definitely be done with the right kind of logic added to the bot. Please be as specific as possible about what the conversation flow should look like and I will try to help.

Comment: My problem was that I didn't know how to manage more than one dialog in  OnMessageActivityAsync method in bot class. When I was invoking Dialog B from controller - I was unable to continue the Dialog B. Instead Dialog A was started. Currently I created DialogState accessor and depending on the active dialog, the bot will select dialog on which it should call RunAsync method.

Comment: Below code allowed me to create dialog context and I used active dialog property to verify which dialog should be called

DialogSet dialogSet = new DialogSet(this.Accessor.ConversationDialogStateAccessor);
DialogContext dialogContext = await dialogSet.CreateContextAsync(turnContext);

Comment: Sounds good. Problem solved, then? If not, please edit your code into your question along with your current problem.